# Is the ideal $x^3-y^5 \subseteq \mathbb{C}[x,y]$ prime? Is it maximal?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, irreducible-polynomials, maximal-and-prime-ideals

I have some idea like I  is a maximal ideal of a commutative ring R iff R/I is a field. but not able to formulate for this case. first, I thought about the irreducibility of  ideal $x^3-y^5 \subseteq \mathbb{C}[x,y]$ and show if $I$ is irreducible then it is prime

Comment: $x^3-y^5$ is irreducible, so the ideal it generates is prime (in a UFD). However, it is properly contained for example in the ideals $I_1=\langle x,y\rangle$ and $I_2=\langle x-1,y-1\rangle$.

Comment: @marwalix How could this be a maximal ideal? After all, it describes a curve. And that curve consists of smaller entities, aka points, associated with bigger ideals.

Comment: @Jykri Lahtonen You’re right. The ideal is prime but not maximal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the ring homomorphism $\phi: \mathbb{C}[x,y] \to  \mathbb{C}[t]$ given by $f(x,y) \mapsto f(t^5,t^3)$.

Then $\ker \phi = \langle x^3-y^5 \rangle =I$.

Now $\operatorname{im}\phi$ is a domain because it is a subring of $\mathbb{C}[t]$, which is a domain. Therefore, $I$ is prime.

On the other hand, the units of $\mathbb{C}[t]$ are $\mathbb{C}^*$ and so $\operatorname{im}\phi$ is not a field. Therefore, $I$ is not maximal.